# Oracle security ADF Faces Error 401--Unauthorized JDeveloper 12C

Tags: java, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

Please is POST not a duplicate of [Oracle ADF Secured App Gives HTTP 401 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209417/oracle-adf-secured-app-gives-http-401-error)

I'am having this error when trying to access a protected page within ADF Secure application with **Jdeveloper 12C**.

I try the same things on **JDeveloper 11.1.2.0.0**  and everything goes normally.

```
Error 401--Unauthorized

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.2 401 Unauthorized
```

Does somebody known the problem? Is this a bug in  Jdeveloper 12C?

Comment: How is this *not* a duplicate, exactly?  Same error, same envrionment...

Comment: @Charles  Of course. I'am using Jdeveloper 12C and not 11..... i also explain that the same application works correctly on Jdeveloper 11....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youp!

I get it now running on Jdeveloper 12c. The probleme was that i have some corrupted files in my application which always force default Authentictor to ignore that an user  authentication is  successful.

I just create a brand new application, migrate the jsf pages and also a new ADF Secure configuration.

Comment: Hello Festus I was curious how many jsf pages and jsff you had to migrate for this project.  Did you recreate the jsf pages or just the application?  Thank you in advance.